# Triggers not reflecting on procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, trigger

I have a `trigger`

```
create trigger flightinput2 on reservation 
after insert 
as 
begin
update reservation 
  set Departure_Airport='LDN',
      Arrival_Airport='KUL' 
  where Flight_Code='EM0088'
end
```

then I have a procedure to modify `Flight_Code` say from "MH0077" to "EM0088"

```
create procedure modifyvalue @ID int,@flightcode varchar(6), @date datetime as 
begin 
update reservation 
  set Departure_Time=@date,
      Flight_code=@flightcode 
  where ID=@ID

  select * from reservation 
end 

drop procedure modifyvalue

execute modifyvalue '12','EM0088','2014-08-16'
```

The result I get made changes to `Flight_Code` and other necessary data from the procedure but not the `departure_airport` and `arrival_airport` as the designed trigger.

I hope I explained my situation clear enough. What did I do wrong, I figured I might not doing this the correct way for the trigger to fire

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is designed to only fire after an insert not an update. Try changing the code to:-

```
create trigger flightinput2 on reservation AFTER INSERT, UPDATE as 
begin
   update reservation set Departure_Airport='LDN',Arrival_Airport='KUL' where Flight_Code='EM0088'
end
```

EDIT:- As pointed out, the code above will update all records within the database that have a flight code of EM0088

To prevent this you could update the code to:-

```
 create trigger flightinput2 on reservation 
 after insert, update
 as 
 begin
      update reservation 
        set Departure_Airport='LDN',
            Arrival_Airport='KUL' 
        from inserted ins
  inner join reservation r on ins.PrimaryKeyColumn = r.PrimaryKeyColumn
       where r.Flight_Code='EM0088'
  end
```

Just change PrimaryKeyColumn to the PK of your table.

EDIT2 - If you want to change values in the table based on flight codes you could do this:-

```
  create trigger flightinput1 on reservation 
  after update
  as 
  begin

  declare @code char(10);

  select @code = 
    ins.flight_code
  from inserted ins

  if @code = 'MH0007'
    update reservation 
    set Departure_Airport='XXXX',
    Arrival_Airport='KUL' 
    from reservation r
    inner join inserted ins1 on ins1.resid = r.resid 

  else if @code = 'EM0088'
    update reservation 
    set Departure_Airport='LDNXX',
    Arrival_Airport='KUL' 
    from reservation r
    inner join inserted ins1 on ins1.resid = r.resid 

  end
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64581/discussion-on-answer-by-dbafromthecold-triggers-not-reflecting-on-procedure).

Answer (score 1):

First, drop the triggers you have. There is absolutely no reason to be doing this with multiple triggers.

Then:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.FlightInput
ON dbo.Reservation 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE r
    SET Depature_Airport = CASE i.flight_code
      WHEN 'EM0088' THEN 'LDN'
      WHEN 'MH0007' THEN 'something else' END,
    Arrival_Airport = CASE i.flight_code
      WHEN 'EM0088' THEN 'KUL'
      WHEN 'MH0007' THEN 'something else' END
  FROM dbo.Reservation AS r
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i
  ON r.ID = i.ID
  WHERE i.flight_code IN ('EM0088','MH0007');
END
GO
```